# Spring-security: remember me token working only one time

Tags: spring-security, remember-me

I'm experiencing a really weird issue with spring security.

The remember-me token seems to last for only one automatic login, after that, it stops working.

*1. After login:*

[image]

*2. Then, I manually delete the JSESSIONID cookie and reload the page*

[image]

*3. I delete the JSESSIONID cookie again and reload the page again.*

**Now, I'm logged out!**

In the console I get this:

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.CookieTheftException: Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch. Implies previous cookie theft attack.
```

I read that this might be the result of the browser issuing multiple requests at the same time, I checked (disabled all the resources, leaving only plain HTML, but to no avail)

[image]

Here's my configuration

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.formLogin().permitAll();    
        http.rememberMe().tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);

        http.logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepository.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return tokenRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pulling dataSource from config worked for me, try it

```
@Autowired
JpaConfiguration jpaConfig;

@Bean(name = "persistentTokenRepository")
public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
    JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
    tokenRepository.setDataSource(jpaConfig.dataSource());
    return tokenRepository;
}
```

or you can also try to increase token validity

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.formLogin().permitAll();    
        http.rememberMe().tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
            .tokenValiditySeconds(1209600);

        http.logout().permitAll();
    }
```